# ERROR: [example/path] is not a valid editable requirement - python

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, requirements.txt

I made a websocketserver to push in docker container, but there is one library I've been installed in my venv via local directory it is located in my Desktop so I navigate in desktop directory then used a pip command "pip install -e ." But when I start to build an image for docker the error persist, kindly see the image below.

[image: docker error while building an image]

requirements.txt

```
aiodns==3.0.0
aiohttp==3.8.1
aiosignal==1.2.0
async-timeout==4.0.2
asyncio==3.4.3
attrs==21.4.0
ccxt==1.91.52
# Editable install with no version control (ccxtpro==1.2.6)
-e c:\users\hp\desktop\ccxt.pro-master\python\
certifi==2022.5.18.1
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
cryptography==37.0.2
frozenlist==1.3.0
gevent==21.12.0
greenlet==1.1.2
idna==3.3
multidict==6.0.2
pycares==4.1.2
pycparser==2.21
requests==2.28.0
SimpleWebSocketServer==0.1.1
urllib3==1.26.9
websockets==10.3
yarl==1.7.2
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

Dockerfile

```
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.10.1-slim

WORKDIR /copyTrading

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
    
CMD [ "python", "server2.py"]
```

Comment: You cannot have `c:\users\hp\desktop\ccxt.pro-master\python` folder in Docker image. What do you *expect*? Is it some local package (then copy it to Docker image and use the destination path as editable requirement)? Third-party package not on PyPi (then copy it too or use `git` installation option)?